# While uploading video using antd upload i'm facing this issue - "dataURLtoImage(): dataURL is illegal"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, frontend, antd

I'm using antd video upload component... while uploading video. i'm facing this error,

```
   dataURLtoImage(): dataURL is illegal
   at r.onerror (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:307537:52)
```

My code is,

```
 const handleUpload = async (file) => {
  setUplodedFiles(file);
 if (file.size < maxAllowedMediaSize[file.type?.split("/")[0]]) {
  compressAccurately(file, 100).then(async (res) => {
    const base64 = await convertBase64(res);
    setUploadedFileBase64(base64);
  });
 }

 return false;
};

const convertBase64 = (file) => {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const fileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

  fileReader.onload = () => {
    resolve(fileReader.result);
  };

  fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
    reject(error);
   };
  });
  };
```

Can anybody help me